# C++ How to scale a shape and create an if function to not print if too big after scale?

Tags: c++, function, class, scale, shapes

given a shapes orignal centroid + vertices .. i.e. if its a triangle, i know all three vertices coords. How could i then create a scaling function with a scaling factor as a parameter as below.. however my current code is with error and the result are huge shapes, much more than what im scaling by (only want scale factor of 2).

```html
void Shape::scale(double factor)
{
 int x, y, xx, xy;
 int disx, disy;
 for (itr = vertices.begin(); itr != vertices.end(); ++itr) {
  //translate obj to origin (0,0)
  x = itr->getX() - centroid.getX();
  y = itr->getY() - centroid.getY();

  //finds distance between centroid and vertex
  disx = x + itr->getX();
  disy = y + itr->getY();
  
  xx = disx * factor;
  xy = disy * factor;

  //translate obj back
  xx = xx + centroid.getX();
  xy = xy + centroid.getY();

  //set new coord
  itr->setX(xx);
  itr->setY(xy);
 }
}
```

I know of using iterations to run through the vertices, my main point of confusion is how can i do the maths between the factor to scale my shapes size?

this is how i declare and itialise a vertex

```
// could i possible do (scale*x,scale*y)? or would that be problematic..
vertices.push_back(Vertex(x, y));
```

Also.. the grid is i.e. 100x100. if a scaled shape was to be too big to fit into that grid, i want an exit from the scale function so that the shape wont be enlarged, how can this be done effectively? so far i have a for look but that just loops on vertices, so it will only stop those that would be outside the grid, instead of cancelling the entire shape which would be ideal

if my question is too broad, please ask and i shall edit further to standard

Comment: Not that it's too broad, but "how do I calculate the centroid of a polygon" is definitely off-topic.

Comment: i know the centroids, the shapes are already created so decl a centroid is a parameter.. centroid is also key piece to scaling any shape

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to do is find the center of mass of your set of points. That is the arithmetic mean of the coordinates of your points. Then, for each point calculate the line between the center of mass and that point. Now the only thing left is to put the point on that line, but in `factor * current_distance` away, where current_distance is the distance from the mass center to the given point before rescaling.

```
void Shape::scale(double factor)
{

  Vertex mass_center = Vertex(0., 0.);

  for(int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
  {
    mass_center.x += vertices[i].x;
    mass_center.y += vertices[i].y;
  }

  mass_center.x /= vertices.size();
  mass_center.y /= vertices.size();

  for(int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
  {
    //this is a vector that leads from mass center to current vertex
    Vertex vec = Vertex(vertices[i].x - mass_center.x, vertices[i].y - mass_center.y);
    vertices[i].x = mass_center.x + factor * vec.x;
    vertices[i].y = mass_center.y + factor * vec.y;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, big help towards my solution, in my edit of the post ive put what ive currently got so far in my function, it scapes, but the shapes are enormous to what they should be, (by default i just need to scale x2), and instead they are maybe 3 or four times over so theres obviously an error in my code which i cant yet identify

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the centroid of a shape and the vertexes are the distance from that point then scaling in rectangular coordinates is just multiplying the x and y components of each vertex by the appropriate scaling factor (with a negative value flipping the shape around the axis.

```
void Shape::scale(double x_factor, double y_factor){
  for(auto i=0; i < verticies.size();++i){
    verticies[i].x *= x_scale;
    verticies[i].y *= y_scale;
  }
}
```

You could then just overload this function with one that takes a single parameter and calls this function with the same value for `x` and `y`.

```
void Shape::scale(double factor){
  Shape::scale(factor, factor);
}
```

If you're vertex values are not centered at the origin then you will also have to multiply those values by your scaling factor.